# Gradle error: Execution failed for task ':crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsArmRelease'. > Crashlytics Developer Tools error

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I had setup crashlytics to get ndk crashes for my Android app. Crashes are getting recorded in crashlytics but I am not getting the line numbers.

Went through: https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/605190-missing-line-numbers-in-native-crashes

I am getting the following error on running below command:

```
./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsArmRelease
```

**What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsArmRelease'.
Crashlytics Developer Tools error.**

I have tried various solutions but nothing is helping.

Comment: is `ArmRelease` a valid flavor? Adding your build.gradle to the question could be usefull

Comment: @MatPag I use `assembleArmRelease` to create the build. So I guess its valid.
First I tried with just `crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease` as suggested by crashlytics FAQ but then gradle gave me an error and suggested me to use `crashlyticsUploadSymbolsArmRelease`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking: I had the same problem and found the correct command in the Gradle view:

```
app->Tasks->other->crashlyticsUploadSymbolsMYAPPVARIANTNAME
```

You can search the gradle tasks in the gradle window as well by just starting to type:

[image]